# How can I stop Chrome/IE from centering table Row

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table layout (see below) that has 2 rows, with the second row containing a table:

```
<table id="outer">
  <tr>..</tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table id="inner">..</table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The CSS is setting the outer table to a height: 100%.  The inner table is setting a height: 100%.

**Problem:**

If A) the first row of the outer table is empty and
   B) the content within the inner table is minimal, it vertically aligns the inner table      (or the second row of the outer table) on the page, despite the fact that I have height 100% for the inner table.

**NOTE:**

Firefox shows it the way I am expecting it so that if the first row of the outer table is empty, the inner table (or second row of the outer table) will be vertically aligned at the top.

I have tried using vertical-align: top in different ways to no avail.

Any suggestions?

**Browsers**
IE 7/8
Chrome 17.0.963

Comment: [Why do you have nested tables in the first place?](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/)

Comment: Is the ID of the second table supposed to be `inner`?

Comment: Make a JSFiddle so that you can show the problem

Comment: @Quentin I don't have control over what is in place.

Comment: @Matt Grande: Yes, I edited it.

Comment: Got to love the -1 mark for some unknown reason.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be in a part of your code that you have not shown us. As you will see from the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BS3zq/1/), Chrome and Firefox both have no problem displaying the table with the first row collapsed, which means that you have another line of CSS which is affecting this table (perhaps from a CSS Reset).